# C#/XAML LaunchUriAsync doesn't work on simulator

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

In my app i want to open an URL in the default browser of Windows:

```
 Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.hello.com");
 var launched = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
```

This perfectly works on the LocalMachine but doesn't work if i launch it from the simulator.

In the simulator, the result is that the app is supended, and the control jump to the Desktop...nothing else...
Someone know how to make it works?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related with Chrome Browser...just in case change the default browser to IE and also in the simulator the LaunchUriAsync perfectly works!